# why do match one more time occurence in this string?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to teach my student the about perl with "*" .

This is my example of php string:

```
$str = "go";
```

this is my mode:

```
$mode = "/g*/";
```

when I get result with pre_match_all, some strange thing happen!

```
preg_match_all($mode,$str,$out);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($out);
```

this is my print of $out:

```
array (
  0 =>
  array (
    0 => 'g',
    1 => '',
    2 => '',
  ),
)
```

I expected there should be only two matching results：'g' and ''; why ?

Comment: sorry , it mean preg_match_all("/g*/","go",$out);

Comment: That doesn't look strange to me at all. Your pattern says, match all occurences of a literal "g" zero or more times. There are three matches found in your text. See [this](https://regex101.com/r/VCJK4s/5)

Comment: you mean it matchs "g" , "go", and "o"?

Comment: @limingshen `g*` means "0 or more g's". It starts at the start of the string, and matches the first "g". Then it continues to the next position (between g and o) and matches again (it finds 0 g's), so you get an empty match. Then it continues again to the next position (right after the o) and matches again 0 g's so you get another empty match.